# Force input type date to render in English?

Tags: android, html, ios

Currently we have input type date in our html page in Android and IOS. But its showing in Arabic. Can we force the calendar in English language.

[image]

[image]

Comment: HTML code snippet would be very helpful. What have you already tried?

Comment: its from Mozilla site check image